# C/C++ struct in C# via P/Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, pinvoke

I am taking my first steps using P/Invoke and try to represent these C/C++ structs:

```
#ifndef struct_emxArray_char_T_1024
#define struct_emxArray_char_T_1024
struct emxArray_char_T_1024
{
    char_T data[1024];
    int32_T size[1];
};

#ifndef typedef_e_struct_T
#define typedef_e_struct_T
typedef struct
{
    emxArray_char_T_1024 value1;
    real_T value2;
    uint32_T value3;
    boolean_T value4;
} e_struct_T;
```

using this in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class emxArray_char_T_1024
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
    public string data;
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int size;
}

StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class e_struct_T
{
    emxArray_char_T_1024 value1;
    double value2;
    uint value3;
    bool value4;
}
```

Does this look sufficient? I am not too sure about the comments like this in the tutorial:

```
compile with: /target:module
```

PS:

The above 'types' seem to be defined like this:

```
typedef double real_T;
typedef unsigned int uint32_T;
typedef unsigned char boolean_T;
typedef char char_T;
typedef int int32_T;
```

Comment: Just to start: how real_T is defined? float or double? boolean_T? byte or int? char_T? wchar_t or char?

Comment: Thanks Adriano. Did not realize that these 'types' are not common. Had a look in the header files and found the stuff in PS (see edited question).

Comment: OK, System.Boolean is 4 bytes so it has be decorared with MarshalAs. Everything else looks OK to me.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind posting an answer then with the correct attribute for Boolean please?

Comment: You can use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]

Comment: Thanks. Please post this as answer if you do not mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final struct looks OK to me, the only change you should do is how your `boolean_T` is marshaled. Default C-style `bool` is one byte signed integer so it must be marshaled as `I1`. You declared `boolean_T` it as `unsigned char` so it should be `U1`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class e_struct_T
{
    emxArray_char_T_1024 value1;
    double value2;
    uint value3;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] 
    bool value4;
}
```

Comment: I am having a closer look at this. value2 seems to be always zero. Maybe it is too naive to assume that I can just use double for real_T? Thanks.

Comment: No, it should be OK. Try to replace value2 with, for example, an int to check what you get there. It may be a disalignment of the other struct.

Comment: Mmmh, just looking at emxArray_char_T_1024. Is int32_T size[1] -> [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] public int size actaully correct?

Comment: By chance I thought it could be, can you try with **[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=1)] public int[] size**?